# Light on wireframes in DoubleSide

Tags: three.js

I can't get light on wireframes inside the geometry. 
For example I create `IcosahedronGeometry` (`MeshPhongMaterial`) and set point light. When side is set to DoubleSide or BackSide, I can see light on the faces. But when I set on wireframes, then in BackSide there is light on frames, but in DoubleSide there isn't. 
In my opinion in DoubleSide and wireframes there should be light seen on the frames inside and outside the geometry.

Comment: (1) Lines do not have vertex normals, so it does not make sense to use `MeshPhongMaterial` with them. Lines do not have a "side", either. What you are trying to do is not supported. (2) If you want to render a mesh using a wireframe-like material that supports lights, you will have to create a custom `ShaderMaterial` using the technique demonstrated in [this three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_wireframe.html).

Comment: Ok, but when I set side to BackSide I can see light on wireframes inside the geometry. Why? And thx for example :)